# Follow more than one link with vimperator

Tags: vimperator

when I google for something and want to follow a link in a new tab I write ":F" and then the link number. How do I follow more than one link? Say I would like to open the links 12 - 17 in new tabs at the same time, can this be done?

Comment: I think it is not possible right now, but I like the idea.

Comment: Now it is. :) See my answer below.

Answer (score 13):

Updating thread:

<kbd>;</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> followed by links numbers you want to open, so say:

`;F 7 12 15` will open links number 7 12 and 15 in next tabs.

is what you're after, in my Vimperator version no new plugins are required for this. I have 3.8.2 but I think this was added even earlier, though am not certain.

Comment: Does not work for me. I press `;` then `F` then type a number, and as soon as it matches, vimperator will follow that hint immediately. No chance to enter further numbers.

Comment: Sorry, it works, just not on links with `rel="nofollow"`

Answer (score 2):

Try buffer-multipe-hints.js plugin.
This plugin modifies ";F" hints.

(buffer-multipls-hints.js requires _libly.js)

[buffer-multiple-hints.js on vimpr](https://github.com/vimpr/vimperator-plugins/blob/master/buffer-multiple-hints.js)
[_libly.js on vimpr](https://github.com/vimpr/vimperator-plugins/blob/master/_libly.js)